# JWT token is always invalid when verified

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am new to node.js, express and JWT. I found similar questions here but they didn't help.

I am able to login and store the token in local storage but when I try set Authorization header for another request with the same token, it fails verification in the server. I checked the token both from the server and client, they are exactly the same but the verification is failing, please help !

Here is the code I am using to verify the token.

```
exports.verify = function(req, res, next) {
    let accessToken = req.headers.authorization
    if (!accessToken){
        return res.status(403).send()
    }
    
    let payload
    try{
        // Never makes it through this

        payload = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
        next()
    }
    catch(e){
        
        return res.status(401).json({success: false, message: "token expired or invalid"})
    }
}
```

Here in `app.js` file I use the `verify` function like this for another route.

```
const { verify } = require('./controllers/auth')

const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes')

app.use('/user', verify, userRoutes)
```

Where am I going wrong here ?

EDIT:

I added `console.log(e)` in the `verify` function, inside the `catch()` and got the the below result.

> TokenExpiredError: jwt expired
> at /home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:152:21
> at getSecret (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
> at exports.verify (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/controllers/auth.js:62:23)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
> at /home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
> at Function.process_params (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
> at next (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
> at cookieParser (/home/shashank/Documents/sms/server/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:57:14)
> {   expiredAt: 2020-10-29T17:30:31.000Z }

Let me show my .env file where I store the secret key info

```
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=swsh23hjddnns
ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE=3600
REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=dhw782wujnd99ahmmakhanjkajikhiwn2n
REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFE=86400
```

So, the access token has to last an hour right ?

The token is created like below

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

// Not using a database right now.
let users = {
    email: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    password: 'password'
}

exports.login = function(req, res) {

    let email = req.body.email
    let password = req.body.password
    
    // Simple validation !
    if (!email || !password || users.email !== email || users.password !== password){
        return res.status(401).json({success: false, message: "Incorrect username or password"})
    }    


    //use the payload to store information about the user such as username, user role, etc.
    let payload = {email: email}

    //create the access token with the shorter lifespan
    let accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        algorithm: "HS256",
        expiresIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE
    })

    //create the refresh token with the longer lifespan
    let refreshToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        algorithm: "HS256",
        expiresIn: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFE
    })

    //store the refresh token in the user array
    users.refreshToken = refreshToken

    //send the access token to the client inside a cookie
    // res.cookie("jwt", accessToken, { httpOnly: true})   //secure: false,   use this along with httpOnly: true in production
    
    // res.setHeader('Authorization', accessToken); 
    res.json({
        accessToken: accessToken,
        success: true, message: "Authentication success"
    });
    res.send()

}
```

Comment: can you show where you create the token and how the env vars are used

Comment: so the token is simply expired. Either it's just beyond the time you set (deliberately) or you made a mistake setting the expiration and the expiration comes earlier than expected. But you see, it's important to see all the details, and later in your code you can also react to dofferent exception in a different way.

Comment: So, I login and a few seconds later make a request, but the token is supposed to last  an hour ! , do you think it's something to do with timezones ? I am not sure.  @LawrenceCherone I have updated the question details for you.

Comment: can you show the actual token or just the values of iat and exp when you decode it on https://jwt.io?

Comment: I just sent the value of process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE in the response, it came as "3600" , maybe that was the problem ? Then I tried `parseInt()`  when setting the expiration time, now I don't get status 401 in the response,  thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem you are experiencing is because of how you are storing the time out period.

From the Documentation for [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme)

> expiresIn: expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span
> zeit/ms. Eg: 60, "2 days", "10h", "7d". A numeric value is interpreted
> as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time
> units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by
> default ("120" is equal to "120ms").

Because you are storing in your process.env, it looks like it is translating it to a string, instead of maintaining the integer value.

Test Code:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
require('dotenv').config();
let payload = {email: 'email'}
let accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
    algorithm: "HS256",
    expiresIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE
})
console.log(accessToken);
console.log('waiting 4 seconds');
setTimeout(function() {
    let val = jwt.verify(accessToken, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    console.log(val);
}, 4000);
```

With the following process.env values, it fails

```
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=swsh23hjddnns
ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE=3600
REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=dhw782wujnd99ahmmakhanjkajikhiwn2n
REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFE=86400
```

But if we change the ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE to

```
ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFE=3600S
```

It succeeds

Without the time unit, any request that is delayed by more than 3.6 Seconds will error out.